# trouble importing precompiled version of PIL on linux

Tags: python, import, python-imaging-library

I am writing a plugin for Ultimaker Cura which uses the Python Imaging Library.
Cura has it's own python environment and uses Python 3.5.7.

I want my plugin to be usable for any Cura user, so I have to include PIL in my plugin inside a subdirectory, and because it's _imaging module is written in C, I have to include precompiled versions of PIL for Python 3.5 which i got from here: https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/#files

I included the cp35 win_amd64 version for windows under "lib_win" and the cp35 manylinux1_x86_64 version for linux under "lib_linux". Here is my code:

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "lib_win"))
    from PIL import Image
    from PIL import ImageFilter
    from PIL import ImageFont
    from PIL import ImageDraw
    from PIL import ImageChops

if sys.platform == 'linux':
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "lib_linux"))
    from PIL import Image
    from PIL import ImageFilter
    from PIL import ImageFont
    from PIL import ImageDraw
    from PIL import ImageChops
```

This works without any issues for windows. Under linux, i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/dipl/.local/share/cura/4.6/plugins/SVGReader/lib_linux/PIL/Image.py", line 93, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging'
```

I have "_imaging.cpython-35m-i386-linux-gnu.so" inside the lib_linux/PIL directory, but it does not recognize this.

I have checked other posts with the same error, but they either have older versions of PIL installed, or use the wrong precompiled version, or are missing a DLL. None of this is the case here.

I also have a working version of PIL on my linux system, and the include code and the PIL code look exactly the same, only the python version number is different.

In case you need it, here is the full sys.path for the Cura python environment (my plugin is SVGReader): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mixzi.png
(Had to use my own console because Cura doesn't come with one)

So, why does it not recognize _imaging? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

in case anybody has the same issue, it's really just as simple as changing the filename of the _imaging library. Name it _imaging.so, or create a symlink to it called _imaging.so. No idea why it works on other platforms without doing that. Might need to rename some other stuff in the same manner, too.